# How do I solve the "Unfortunately, System UI has stopped." on Gionee S6 Pro?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

I seem to be getting the error "Unfortunately, System UI has stopped." on my Gionee S6 Pro. I have tried wiping cache partition via recovery with no progress. The OS is Marshmallow and UI is Amigo. The touch screen is unresponsive, but I can press the close button after error pops up. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Seems issue is with all Gionee S6 models

Answer (score 0):

the issue is with all gionee S6 model. The best way out of this is to do a factory reset. But u may loose ur files on ur storage.

Answer (score 0):

The stock  launcher for this model seems  buggy, and apparently there is no fix at the moment.

To solve your problem, try  installing a third-party launcher such as **[Nova Launcher](http://novalauncher.com/),** **[Google Now launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.launcher)** or any other launcher...